# the python script works in a minimized window with full access to the PC

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a question about python, how can I write a script so that the actions in it work only in the window with the game I need and I can use the PC? (I didn't find any information as such, I want to write a bot for the game, I hope you will help me, it's just my 1 script and generally my first job in programming, because of this I have a lot of questions) I work at PyCharm

Comment: [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news)?

Comment: I did not use pygame, I need to simulate the actions of a "player" in a ready-made game, but so that this imitation does not interfere with using a PC in parallel. At the expense of actions, most of my actions involve a mouse, how do I make sure that this mouse is involved in a certain window I need, and not on the PC as a whole